# Pass SSH object to subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, function, ssh

I am trying to pass an SSH object to a subroutine. When I call `doSomething($ssh)` this function appears to hang and not return any output.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $myHost  = 'localhost'; 
my @keyfile = "/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new(
    $myHost,
    identity_files => \@keyfile
);

$ssh->register_handler("stdout", sub {
    my ($channel, $buffer) = @_;
    print $buffer->bytes;
});


$ssh->login('userB');
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("whoami;hostname;pwd");

doSomething($ssh);

sub doSomething {
    my $sshref = shift;
    $sshref->login('userA');
    my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $sshref->cmd("whoami;hostname;pwd");
}
```

Comment: It seems to be as if I cannot call the login method twice on the $ssh object and I have to create a new instance of the $ssh object (as $ssh2) for instance and then call login on that.. Any ideas on how I can re-use the existing object?

Comment: You can't, once authentication succeeds, the SSH protocol doesn't allow one to re-authenticate. If you want to change user, you have to open a new connection.

Comment: Thanks @salva. This works now. Just created a new SSH object.

Comment: @salva Care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment that:

> It seems to be as if I cannot call the login method twice on the $ssh object and I have to create a new instance of the $ssh object (as $ssh2) for instance and then call login on that.. Any ideas on how I can re-use the existing object?

You can't, once authentication succeeds, the SSH protocol doesn't allow one to re-authenticate. If you want to change user, you have to open a new connection.

*(Answered by [salva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124951/salva) in the comments)*